# Permanent Routes Centos Questions

Tags: centos, routes

So with a little help I figured out how to setup these routes and I can set them in rc.local

route add -net 208.82.236.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev ppp0 metric 1

route add -net 208.82.236.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0 metric 10

my question is being that the first route is ppp0 as soon as I disconnect the modem the route is dropped how do I maintain the route or make it permanent so that next time the modem connects it will follow the route.

Currently after ppp0 disconnects the route is dropped

> netstat -r Kernel IP routing table
>
> Destination     Gateway
>
> Genmask         Flags   MSS Window 
>   irtt Iface laxapx03.o1.com *
>
> 255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
>
> 208.82.236.0    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
>
> 10.0.1.0        *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
>
> 169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
>
> default         10.0.1.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0

Comment: How are you establishing the modem connection? That's going to determine what you hook into to re-establish your routes.

Comment: wvdial &[Modem0]
Modem = /dev/ttyS0
Baud = 115200
SetVolume = 1
Dial Command = ATDT
Init1 = ATZ
Init3 = ATM1L1
FlowControl = CRTSCTS

[Dialer Defaults]
Modem = /dev/ttyS0
Baud = 115200
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ISDN = 0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Phone = 2090177
Username = user
Password = pass

Comment: Do I just add the route to /etp/ppp/ip-up/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create executable script in /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/ for example - setroute

## !/bin/sh

route add -net 208.82.236.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev ppp0 metric 1

Comment: Thanks got it, I was adding it to ip-up.local but it wasn't executable, Thanks!